# Make a non-rectangular bottom for div?

Tags: html, css

Any idea on how to make a zigzag effect in the bottom of div with CSS. Is it border type or clip path?

[image: CSS wavy bottom of div]

I tried `border-radius` but it doesn't look good

```css
.element {
  margin:20px;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius:0 0 50px 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.element:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:#fff;
  width:50%;
  bottom:-20px;
  left:20px;
  right:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50px 60px 0 0;
  border-top:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: you can use CSS pseudo-element to achive this kind of styles.

Comment: One should always know the difference between a developer's forum and discussion forum!

Comment: @Sarabjit Singh you can also use background-image to achieve this. that would be easy.

Comment: One way to do it would be to keep absolutely positioned divs on top of it

Comment: You can find here, a tutorial on how to make a non-rectangular [creating-non-rectangular-headers](https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/) using many techniques SVG, image or CSS that you can use on any other div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with multiple background with radial-gradient and apply a drop-shadow filter for the shadow:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#f00,#f00) top/100% calc(100% - 25px),
    radial-gradient(85px 30px at bottom,transparent 50%,#f00 52%) 0 calc(100% - 8px)/80px 20px,
    radial-gradient(85px 30px at 50% 10px,#f00 50%,transparent 52%) 80px 100%/80px 30px,
    radial-gradient(85px 30px at bottom,transparent 50%,#f00 52%) 160px calc(100% - 8px)/80px 20px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

If you want more simply add more gradient alternating them and increasing the background position each time:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#f00,#f00) top/100% calc(100% - 25px),
    
    /* top curve */
    radial-gradient(85px 30px at bottom,transparent 50%,#f00 52%) 0 calc(100% - 8px)/80px 20px,
    /* bottom curve */
    radial-gradient(85px 30px at 50% 10px,#f00 50%,transparent 52%) 80px 100%/80px 30px,
    /* top curve */
    radial-gradient(85px 30px at bottom,transparent 50%,#f00 52%) 160px calc(100% - 8px)/80px 20px,
    /* bottom curve */
    radial-gradient(85px 30px at 50% 10px,#f00 50%,transparent 52%) 240px 100%/80px 30px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

With CSS variable it's easier and you can also control the curve:

```css
.box {
  --p:80px;
  --top:radial-gradient(calc(var(--p) + 5px) 30px at bottom,transparent 50%,#f00 52%);
  --bottom:radial-gradient(calc(var(--p) + 5px) 30px at 50% 10px,#f00 50%,transparent 52%);
  
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#f00,#f00) top/100% calc(100% - 25px),
    
    var(--top)    calc(0*var(--p)) calc(100% - 8px)/var(--p) 20px,
    var(--bottom) calc(1*var(--p)) 100%            /var(--p) 30px,
    var(--top)    calc(2*var(--p)) calc(100% - 8px)/var(--p) 20px,
    var(--bottom) calc(3*var(--p)) 100%            /var(--p) 30px,
    var(--top)    calc(4*var(--p)) calc(100% - 8px)/var(--p) 20px,
    var(--bottom) calc(5*var(--p)) 100%            /var(--p) 30px;;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box" style="--p:100px;">
</div>

<div class="box" style="--p:60px;">
</div>
```

Another simplified syntax:

```css
.box {
  --p:80px;
  --top:radial-gradient(calc(var(--p) + 5px) 30px at bottom,transparent 50%,#f00 52%);
  --bottom:radial-gradient(calc(var(--p) + 5px) 30px at 50% 10px,#f00 50%,transparent 52%);
  
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  padding-bottom:25px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
  background:
    var(--top)    calc(0*var(--p)) calc(100% - 8px),
    var(--bottom) calc(1*var(--p)) 100%            ,
    var(--top)    calc(2*var(--p)) calc(100% - 8px),
    var(--bottom) calc(3*var(--p)) 100%            ,
    var(--top)    calc(4*var(--p)) calc(100% - 8px),
    var(--bottom) calc(5*var(--p)) 100%            ,
    #f00 content-box;
  background-size:var(--p) 20px,var(--p) 30px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box" style="--p:100px;">
</div>

<div class="box" style="--p:60px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could do in a short time and you can tweak it as per your needs. It's not an elegant solution as you have create empty elements and place it absolutely but it does the work.

```css
#wave {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #0d829c;
}

.first {
  position: absolute;
  height: 31px;
  width: 60px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px -1px #0d829c;
}

.second {
  position: absolute;
  height: 31px;
  width: 70px;
  bottom: -12px;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px -1px #0d829c;
}

.third {
  position: absolute;
  height: 31px;
  width: 60px;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px -1px #0d829c;
}

.fourth {
  position: absolute;
  height: 31px;
  width: 60px;
  bottom: -12px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px -1px #0d829c;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
  <div class="fourth"></div>
<div/>
```